# How can I upload videos to Flickr using Uploadr?

Tags: flickr

Flickr Uploadr on OS X scans the folders I selected, but it doesn't count the videos in that folder. If the folder doesn't contain any photos, it simply says:

> No photos

How do I get Uploadr to upload videos to Flickr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the Uploadr app and click the about tab. Then click on the logo to make a hidden menu appear:

[image: Screenshot]

Click "Enable Video Upload" and that's it! You can now upload videos in the formats that Flickr supports.

Reference: [UserVoice request about this issue](https://yahoo.uservoice.com/forums/211185-us-flickr/suggestions/7380709-mac-uploadr-app-needs-to-upload-video)